# MySQL GROUP BY multiple columns and fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I've tried to search answer here, there are few questions are quite similar with my question but i still can't figure out how to GROUP BY below.

MYSQL Structure:

```
ID | USERID | FRIENDID 
1  |   14   |    65
2  |   65   |    14
3  |   12   |    19
4  |   19   |    12
```

How to GROUP BY ID 1 & ID 2 and ID 3 & ID 4 with php query?

Result:

```
1. 14 & 65 
2. 12 & 19
```

Comment: You can't use `GROUP BY` to group by two different values. Do you just want to return the relationships (i.e. user 14 is related to 65)?

Comment: Hi Ben, i want to display only 1 result, either 14&65 or 65&14.

Comment: I understand that - but my question really is how you determine that only those two should be displayed. Is it when one `USERID` is already existing in `FRIENDID`?

Comment: And you want to return the `USERID` and `FRIENDID` fields, rather than the `ID`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT LEAST(USERID, FRIENDID) as x, 
       GREATEST(USERID, FRIENDID) as y
FROM   TableName
GROUP  BY x, y
```

- [SQLFIddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3a21/3)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT CONCAT(USERID, ' & ', FRIENDID) FROM table
```

Comment: It returns 4 rows, when the question asked for only distinct pairs to be returned.

Comment: My solution does what you ask - i.e. return the results grouped like this "id1 & id2". Perhaps you need to improve the wording of your question

Comment: @BenM nowhere in the question is the word "distinct" mentioned

Comment: `GROUP BY ID 1 & ID 2 **and** ID 3 & ID 4` <-- that's a direct quote. Heck, he even indicated his desired output...

Comment: The wording of this question is still appalling, it even asks for a php query. Any wonder I assumed the desired output was a loose example of the row output, rather than the specific result set...

Comment: Not really, but your answer doesn't make use of any grouping or uniqueness whatsoever! ;)

Comment: *sigh* I'm not trying to argue my answer higher here, but to point out that this question is poorly phrased; making it hard for future users to gain any usefulness from this discussion. The fact the question needed specific comment discussion before an answer could be provided points toward this fact.